# VSTS Gulp build step error

Tags: node.js, build, gulp, azure-devops

I have an issue while setting up build steps in `VSTS`. We use gulp to generate `css` from `less` files. In Visual Studio (Task Runner Explorer) it works fine, but I get the following build error when it's run in VSTS:

> Gulp failed with error: C:\NPM\Modules\gulp.cmd failed with return code: 1

I tried also the example mentioned in [the docs](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/steps/build/gulp) about NPM / Gulp setup, but it didn't work for me either. The only change I applied was setting the path for gulpfile.js. I left the rest untouched (NPM install arguments, Gulp task name, working folders, etc.) Yet I got the error I mentioned above.

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong?

Here's the full log of the failing build step:

> 2016-07-11T12:07:06.7456466Z Set workingFolder to default: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.102.0\tasks\Gulp\0.5.24
>   2016-07-11T12:07:06.9966480Z ##[debug]agent.workFolder=C:\a
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0176485Z ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0186489Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_E43D0F79-1244-42AD-B28B-5B98484615E7
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0186489Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_E43D0F79-1244-42AD-B28B-5B98484615E7_ACCESSTOKEN
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0196487Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0196487Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_E43D0F79-1244-42AD-B28B-5B98484615E7
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0206490Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0206490Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0216488Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CWD
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0216488Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_GULPFILE
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0216488Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_GULPJS
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0226488Z ##[debug]loaded 9
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0226488Z ##[debug]check path : C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.102.0\tasks\Gulp\0.5.24\task.json
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0236481Z ##[debug]set resource file to: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.102.0\tasks\Gulp\0.5.24\task.json
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0236481Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0246486Z ##[debug]gulpFile=C:\a\1\s\MyProject\gulpfile.js
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0246486Z ##[debug]check path : C:\a\1\s\MyProject\gulpfile.js
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0256486Z ##[debug]cwd=C:\a\1\s
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0256486Z ##[debug]path exists: C:\a\1\s
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0276485Z ##[debug]gulp=C:\NPM\Modules\gulp.cmd
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0276485Z ##[debug]check path : C:\NPM\Modules\gulp.cmd
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0286476Z ##[debug]targets=null
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0296489Z ##[debug]C:\NPM\Modules\gulp.cmd arg: []
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0296489Z ##[debug]C:\NPM\Modules\gulp.cmd arg: --gulpfile
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0306484Z ##[debug]C:\NPM\Modules\gulp.cmd pathArg: C:\a\1\s\MyProject\gulpfile.js
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0306484Z ##[debug]C:\NPM\Modules\gulp.cmd arg: C:\a\1\s\MyProject\gulpfile.js
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0316486Z ##[debug]arguments=null
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0316486Z ##[debug]exec tool: C:\NPM\Modules\gulp.cmd
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0316486Z ##[debug]Arguments:
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0326490Z ##[debug]   --gulpfile
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0326490Z ##[debug]   C:\a\1\s\MyProject\gulpfile.js
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.0336484Z [command]C:\NPM\Modules\gulp.cmd --gulpfile C:\a\1\s\MyProject\gulpfile.js
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.9754363Z [12:07:07] Local gulp not found in C:\a\1\s\MyProject
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.9764358Z [12:07:07] Try running: npm install gulp
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.9844369Z ##[debug]rc:1
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.9854369Z ##[debug]success:false
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.9874369Z ##[debug]taskRunner fail
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.9894368Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
>   2016-07-11T12:07:07.9964345Z ##[error]Gulp failed with error: C:\NPM\Modules\gulp.cmd failed with return code: 1

And the content of `package.json`

```
{
    "name": "package",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "3.9.1",
        "gulp-bower": "0.0.13",
        "gulp-config": "0.3.0",
        "gulp-less": "3.0.5",
        "gulp-plumber": "1.1.0",
        "gulp-minify-css": "1.2.4",
        "gulp-watch": "4.3.5"
    }
}
```

And the log of the "npm install" step

> 2016-07-12T09:39:02.2279747Z Set workingFolder to default: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.102.0\tasks\Npm\0.2.14
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9144367Z ##[debug]agent.workFolder=C:\a
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9144367Z ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9154360Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_E43D0F79-1244-42AD-B28B-5B98484615E7
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9154360Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_E43D0F79-1244-42AD-B28B-5B98484615E7_ACCESSTOKEN
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9164387Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9174377Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_E43D0F79-1244-42AD-B28B-5B98484615E7
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9174377Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9184400Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9184400Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_COMMAND
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9194377Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CWD
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9204364Z ##[debug]loaded 8
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9204364Z ##[debug]check path : C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.102.0\tasks\Npm\0.2.14\task.json
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9214362Z ##[debug]set resource file to: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.102.0\tasks\Npm\0.2.14\task.json
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9214362Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9224360Z ##[debug]check path : C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9224360Z ##[debug]npm=C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9224360Z ##[debug]cwd=C:\a\1\s\MyProject
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9234370Z ##[debug]path exists: C:\a\1\s\MyProject
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9234370Z ##[debug]command=install
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9244374Z ##[debug]C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd arg: install
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9244374Z ##[debug]arguments=null
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9254371Z ##[debug]exec tool: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9254371Z ##[debug]Arguments:
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9503609Z ##[debug]   install
>   2016-07-12T09:39:02.9503609Z [command]C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd install
>   2016-07-12T09:39:12.1720721Z npm WARN deprecated gulp-minify-css@1.2.4: Please use gulp-clean-css
>   2016-07-12T09:39:15.5308118Z npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
>   2016-07-12T09:39:15.6948189Z npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
>   2016-07-12T09:39:15.9905269Z npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
>   2016-07-12T09:39:16.0395266Z npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
>   2016-07-12T09:39:16.0945273Z npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
>   2016-07-12T09:39:18.0735789Z npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
>   2016-07-12T09:39:18.1575757Z npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.2.1: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0792916Z package@1.0.0 C:\a\1\s\MyProject
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0792916Z +-- gulp@3.9.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0802920Z | +-- archy@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0802920Z | +-- chalk@1.1.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0812919Z | | +-- ansi-styles@2.2.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0812919Z | | +-- escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0822926Z | | +-- has-ansi@2.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0822926Z | | +-- strip-ansi@3.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0832921Z | | `-- supports-color@2.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0832921Z | +-- deprecated@0.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0832921Z | +-- gulp-util@3.0.7 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0842919Z | | +-- array-differ@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0852917Z | | +-- array-uniq@1.0.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0852917Z | | +-- beeper@1.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0852917Z | | +-- dateformat@1.0.12 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0862905Z | | | +-- get-stdin@4.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0862905Z | | | `-- meow@3.7.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0872918Z | | |   +-- camelcase-keys@2.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0882914Z | | |   | `-- camelcase@2.1.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0882914Z | | |   +-- decamelize@1.2.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0892921Z | | |   +-- loud-rejection@1.6.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0892921Z | | |   | +-- currently-unhandled@0.4.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0892921Z | | |   | | `-- array-find-index@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0902920Z | | |   | `-- signal-exit@3.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0902920Z | | |   +-- map-obj@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0912908Z | | |   +-- normalize-package-data@2.3.5 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0912908Z | | |   | +-- hosted-git-info@2.1.5 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0922912Z | | |   | +-- is-builtin-module@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0922912Z | | |   | | `-- builtin-modules@1.1.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0922912Z | | |   | `-- validate-npm-package-license@3.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0932925Z | | |   |   +-- spdx-correct@1.0.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0932925Z | | |   |   | `-- spdx-license-ids@1.2.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0942918Z | | |   |   `-- spdx-expression-parse@1.0.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0942918Z | | |   |     `-- spdx-exceptions@1.0.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0952912Z | | |   +-- object-assign@4.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0952912Z | | |   +-- read-pkg-up@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0952912Z | | |   | +-- find-up@1.1.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0962919Z | | |   | | +-- path-exists@2.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0962919Z | | |   | | `-- pinkie-promise@2.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0972983Z | | |   | |   `-- pinkie@2.0.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0972983Z | | |   | `-- read-pkg@1.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0972983Z | | |   |   +-- load-json-file@1.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0982914Z | | |   |   | +-- parse-json@2.2.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0982914Z | | |   |   | | `-- error-ex@1.3.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0992965Z | | |   |   | |   `-- is-arrayish@0.2.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0992965Z | | |   |   | `-- pify@2.3.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.0992965Z | | |   |   `-- path-type@1.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1002917Z | | |   +-- redent@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1002917Z | | |   | +-- indent-string@2.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1012920Z | | |   | | `-- repeating@2.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1012920Z | | |   | |   `-- is-finite@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1012920Z | | |   | `-- strip-indent@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1022917Z | | |   `-- trim-newlines@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1022917Z | | +-- fancy-log@1.2.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1032910Z | | | `-- time-stamp@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1032910Z | | +-- gulplog@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1042906Z | | | `-- glogg@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1042906Z | | +-- has-gulplog@0.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1052907Z | | | `-- sparkles@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1052907Z | | +-- lodash._reescape@3.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1062917Z | | +-- lodash._reevaluate@3.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1062917Z | | +-- lodash._reinterpolate@3.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1072954Z | | +-- lodash.template@3.6.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1072954Z | | | +-- lodash._basecopy@3.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1082904Z | | | +-- lodash._basetostring@3.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1082904Z | | | +-- lodash._basevalues@3.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1082904Z | | | +-- lodash._isiterateecall@3.0.9 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1092906Z | | | +-- lodash.escape@3.2.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1092906Z | | | | `-- lodash._root@3.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1102906Z | | | +-- lodash.keys@3.1.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1102906Z | | | | +-- lodash._getnative@3.9.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1112961Z | | | | +-- lodash.isarguments@3.0.8 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1112961Z | | | | `-- lodash.isarray@3.0.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1112961Z | | | +-- lodash.restparam@3.6.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1122906Z | | | `-- lodash.templatesettings@3.1.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1122906Z | | +-- multipipe@0.1.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1132911Z | | | `-- duplexer2@0.0.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1132911Z | | +-- object-assign@3.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1142910Z | | `-- replace-ext@0.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1142910Z | +-- interpret@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1142910Z | +-- liftoff@2.2.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1152910Z | | +-- extend@3.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1152910Z | | +-- findup-sync@0.3.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1162905Z | | +-- flagged-respawn@0.3.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1162905Z | | +-- rechoir@0.6.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1162905Z | | `-- resolve@1.1.7 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1172905Z | +-- minimist@1.2.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1172905Z | +-- orchestrator@0.3.7 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1182907Z | | +-- end-of-stream@0.1.5 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1182907Z | | +-- sequencify@0.0.7 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1192910Z | | `-- stream-consume@0.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1192910Z | +-- pretty-hrtime@1.0.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1192910Z | +-- semver@4.3.6 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1202900Z | +-- tildify@1.2.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1202900Z | | `-- os-homedir@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1212905Z | +-- v8flags@2.0.11 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1212905Z | | `-- user-home@1.1.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1212905Z | `-- vinyl-fs@0.3.14 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1222905Z |   +-- defaults@1.0.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1222905Z |   +-- glob-stream@3.1.18 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1232911Z |   | +-- glob@4.5.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1232911Z |   | +-- minimatch@2.0.10 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1242904Z |   | +-- ordered-read-streams@0.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1242904Z |   | +-- through2@0.6.5 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1242904Z |   | | `-- readable-stream@1.0.34 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1252944Z |   | `-- unique-stream@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1252944Z |   +-- glob-watcher@0.0.6 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1262994Z |   | `-- gaze@0.5.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1262994Z |   |   `-- globule@0.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1262994Z |   |     +-- glob@3.1.21 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1272908Z |   |     | +-- graceful-fs@1.2.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1272908Z |   |     | `-- inherits@1.0.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1282913Z |   |     +-- lodash@1.0.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1282913Z |   |     `-- minimatch@0.2.14 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1292911Z |   +-- graceful-fs@3.0.8 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1292911Z |   +-- mkdirp@0.5.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1292911Z |   | `-- minimist@0.0.8 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1302923Z |   +-- strip-bom@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1302923Z |   | +-- first-chunk-stream@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1312908Z |   | `-- is-utf8@0.2.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1312908Z |   +-- through2@0.6.5 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1312908Z |   | `-- readable-stream@1.0.34 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1322909Z |   `-- vinyl@0.4.6 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1322909Z |     `-- clone@0.2.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1332917Z +-- gulp-bower@0.0.13 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1332917Z | +-- bower@1.7.9 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1332917Z | +-- inquirer@0.11.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1342908Z | | +-- ansi-escapes@1.4.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1342908Z | | +-- ansi-regex@2.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1352906Z | | +-- cli-cursor@1.0.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1352906Z | | | `-- restore-cursor@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1362905Z | | |   +-- exit-hook@1.1.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1362905Z | | |   `-- onetime@1.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1362905Z | | +-- cli-width@1.1.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1372905Z | | +-- figures@1.7.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1372905Z | | | `-- object-assign@4.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1382919Z | | +-- lodash@3.10.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1382919Z | | +-- readline2@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1392917Z | | | +-- code-point-at@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1392917Z | | | | `-- number-is-nan@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1392917Z | | | +-- is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1402909Z | | | `-- mute-stream@0.0.5 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1402909Z | | +-- run-async@0.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1412958Z | | +-- rx-lite@3.1.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1412958Z | | +-- string-width@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1422916Z | | `-- through@2.3.8 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1422916Z | +-- through2@0.6.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1422916Z | | +-- readable-stream@1.0.34 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1432914Z | | | `-- isarray@0.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1432914Z | | `-- xtend@4.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1442914Z | `-- walk@2.3.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1442914Z |   `-- foreachasync@3.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1442914Z +-- gulp-config@0.3.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1452907Z | +-- configfiles@0.3.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1452907Z | | +-- clone@0.1.19 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1462907Z | | +-- flatten@0.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1462907Z | | `-- globule@0.2.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1462907Z | |   +-- glob@3.2.11 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1472977Z | |   | `-- minimatch@0.3.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1472977Z | |   +-- lodash@2.4.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1482918Z | |   `-- minimatch@0.2.14 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1482918Z | |     +-- lru-cache@2.7.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1482918Z | |     `-- sigmund@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1492907Z | +-- expander@0.3.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1492907Z | | +-- getobject@0.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1502905Z | | `-- lodash@2.2.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1502905Z | +-- glob@4.5.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1512906Z | | +-- inflight@1.0.5 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1512906Z | | | `-- wrappy@1.0.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1512906Z | | +-- inherits@2.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1522924Z | | +-- minimatch@2.0.10 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1522924Z | | | `-- brace-expansion@1.1.5 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1532909Z | | |   +-- balanced-match@0.4.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1532909Z | | |   `-- concat-map@0.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1532909Z | | `-- once@1.3.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1542910Z | `-- lodash@3.10.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1542910Z +-- gulp-less@3.0.5 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1552906Z | +-- accord@0.20.5 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1552906Z | | +-- convert-source-map@1.2.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1562922Z | | +-- fobject@0.0.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1562922Z | | | `-- graceful-fs@3.0.8 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1562922Z | | +-- indx@0.2.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1572903Z | | +-- lodash@3.10.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1572903Z | | +-- uglify-js@2.7.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1582910Z | | | +-- async@0.2.10 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1582910Z | | | +-- uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1582910Z | | | `-- yargs@3.10.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1592901Z | | |   +-- camelcase@1.2.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1592901Z | | |   +-- cliui@2.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1602980Z | | |   | +-- center-align@0.1.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1602980Z | | |   | | +-- align-text@0.1.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1602980Z | | |   | | | `-- longest@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1612905Z | | |   | | `-- lazy-cache@1.0.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1612905Z | | |   | +-- right-align@0.1.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1622914Z | | |   | `-- wordwrap@0.0.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1622914Z | | |   `-- window-size@0.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1632914Z | | `-- when@3.7.7 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1632914Z | +-- less@2.7.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1632914Z | | +-- errno@0.1.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1642907Z | | | `-- prr@0.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1642907Z | | +-- graceful-fs@4.1.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1652905Z | | +-- image-size@0.5.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1652905Z | | +-- mime@1.3.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1652905Z | | +-- promise@7.1.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1662905Z | | | `-- asap@2.0.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1662905Z | | `-- source-map@0.5.6 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1672913Z | +-- object-assign@4.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1672913Z | +-- through2@2.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1672913Z | | `-- readable-stream@2.0.6 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1682909Z | |   `-- isarray@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1682909Z | `-- vinyl-sourcemaps-apply@0.2.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1692906Z +-- gulp-minify-css@1.2.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1692906Z | +-- clean-css@3.4.18 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1702908Z | | +-- commander@2.8.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1702908Z | | | `-- graceful-readlink@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1702908Z | | `-- source-map@0.4.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1712904Z | |   `-- amdefine@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1712904Z | +-- object-assign@4.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1722918Z | +-- readable-stream@2.1.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1722918Z | | +-- buffer-shims@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1722918Z | | +-- core-util-is@1.0.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1732907Z | | +-- isarray@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1732907Z | | +-- process-nextick-args@1.0.7 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1742927Z | | +-- string_decoder@0.10.31 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1742927Z | | `-- util-deprecate@1.0.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1752906Z | `-- vinyl-bufferstream@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1752906Z |   `-- bufferstreams@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1752906Z |     `-- readable-stream@1.1.14 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1762930Z +-- gulp-plumber@1.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1762930Z `-- gulp-watch@4.3.5 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1772915Z   +-- anymatch@1.3.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1772915Z   | +-- arrify@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1772915Z   | `-- micromatch@2.3.10 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1782908Z   |   +-- arr-diff@2.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1782908Z   |   | `-- arr-flatten@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1792905Z   |   +-- array-unique@0.2.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1792905Z   |   +-- braces@1.8.5 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1802905Z   |   | +-- expand-range@1.8.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1802905Z   |   | | `-- fill-range@2.2.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1802905Z   |   | |   +-- is-number@2.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1812913Z   |   | |   +-- isobject@2.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1812913Z   |   | |   | `-- isarray@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1822913Z   |   | |   +-- randomatic@1.1.5 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1822913Z   |   | |   `-- repeat-string@1.5.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1822913Z   |   | +-- preserve@0.2.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1832937Z   |   | `-- repeat-element@1.1.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1832937Z   |   +-- expand-brackets@0.1.5 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1842902Z   |   | `-- is-posix-bracket@0.1.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1842902Z   |   +-- extglob@0.3.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1842902Z   |   +-- filename-regex@2.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1852902Z   |   +-- is-extglob@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1852902Z   |   +-- kind-of@3.0.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1862908Z   |   | `-- is-buffer@1.1.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1862908Z   |   +-- normalize-path@2.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1862908Z   |   +-- object.omit@2.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1872909Z   |   | +-- for-own@0.1.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1872909Z   |   | | `-- for-in@0.1.5 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1882905Z   |   | `-- is-extendable@0.1.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1882905Z   |   +-- parse-glob@3.0.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1892905Z   |   | +-- glob-base@0.3.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1892905Z   |   | `-- is-dotfile@1.0.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1892905Z   |   `-- regex-cache@0.4.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1902905Z   |     +-- is-equal-shallow@0.1.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1902905Z   |     `-- is-primitive@2.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1912916Z   +-- chokidar@1.6.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1912916Z   | +-- async-each@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1912916Z   | +-- glob-parent@2.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1922905Z   | +-- is-binary-path@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1922905Z   | | `-- binary-extensions@1.5.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1932905Z   | +-- is-glob@2.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1932905Z   | `-- readdirp@2.1.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1932905Z   |   +-- readable-stream@2.1.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1942905Z   |   | `-- isarray@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1942905Z   |   `-- set-immediate-shim@1.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1952911Z   +-- glob@5.0.15 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1952911Z   | `-- minimatch@3.0.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1962908Z   +-- glob2base@0.0.12 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1962908Z   | `-- find-index@0.1.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1962908Z   +-- path-is-absolute@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1972910Z   +-- readable-stream@2.1.4 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1972910Z   | `-- isarray@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1982905Z   +-- vinyl@0.5.3 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1982905Z   | +-- clone@1.0.2 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1992904Z   | `-- clone-stats@0.0.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1992904Z   `-- vinyl-file@1.3.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.1992904Z     +-- strip-bom@2.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.2002905Z     +-- strip-bom-stream@1.0.0 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.2002905Z     `-- vinyl@1.1.1 
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.2012911Z npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.2012911Z npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.2292905Z ##[debug]rc:0
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.2302910Z ##[debug]success:true
>   2016-07-12T09:39:46.2312909Z ##[debug]task result: Succeeded

Comment: The error message is too general. Can you share the detailed error logs?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I pasted the full log message

Comment: Did you add "npm install" task before "gulp" task? If yes, did you add "gulp" as dependencies in "/package.json" file? The error message indicates that "Local gulp not found".

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT yes, I have 2 steps. 1: npm install (without arguments) and 2: gulp, I pasted the content of package.json

Answer (score 2):

Try updating the "Working Directory" to the path of "package.json" file under the "Advanced" settings of "npm install" task.

Comment: I still have the same issue. I tired changing the Working Directory for the "npm install" task and also in combination with the gulp step - no success

Comment: @Szeki Did you see the gulp installed in "npm install" step?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question with the logs of that step

Comment: @Szeki Is the "package.json" file placed in the same path as "gulpfile.js"?

Comment: Yes, both are in the same folder, and that path is set as Working Directory

Comment: @Szeki That's weird. Will it work if you add one more "npm install" step with argument "gulp" and same working directory before Gulp step?

Comment: Yes, with the 2 npm install steps (without arguments and with 'gulp') it is green (do you have any ideas why?)

Comment: @Szeki Do you have blank space in working directory path?

Comment: Yes, the path contains spaces

Comment: @Szeki It seems that the old issue occurs again: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/366. I will report it. Please use two npm install step as a work around for now.

Comment: Eddie, your workaround saved me! Any idea when this will be fixed for real?